# How to make this SELECT query sort alphabetically. Drop down menu. Order by

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
  `$optnamear = tep_db_query("SELECT `products_options_values_name` from `products_options_values` WHERE `products_options_values_id`='$id[products_options_values_id]' ") ;`
```

And I want it to sort the products_options_values_name in the drop down menu alphabetically. How do I do this?

I have been trying to use "order by" but I am clueless about it, any help appreciated

this is the all the code if its needed? Like I said, clueless....

```
   $mainhtml = ""; //the var to hold all of the html

foreach ( $opts as $opt => $name) {

    unset($html);

    $html = "<tr><td width='125px'>
                $name 
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <SELECT name='$opt' onchange='document.m_srch.submit();'>
            <OPTION value='not'>---</OPTION>";//print the name of the box and start the drop down

    $sql = "SELECT `products_options_values_id` from `products_options_values_to_products_options` WHERE `products_options_id`='$opt'"; 
    $res = tep_db_query($sql);// get the values of all the options for that catagory
    while($id = tep_db_fetch_array($res)){

        $optnamear = tep_db_query("SELECT `products_options_values_name` from `products_options_values` WHERE `products_options_values_id`='$id[products_options_values_id]' ") ;

        $optname = tep_db_fetch_array($optnamear);

        //create the dropdown

        $html .= "<OPTION value='$id[products_options_values_id]' ";

        if($_GET[$opt] == $id['products_options_values_id']){
            $html .= "selected='selected'"; // if the product has already been selected keep it selected!
            } 

        $html .= ">$optname[products_options_values_name]</OPTION>";


        }

        $mainhtml .= $html."</SELECT></td></tr>";



    } 


echo "<tr><td>
<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td height='14' class='infoBoxHeading'><img src='images/infobox/corner_left.gif' border='0' alt='' width='11' height='14'></td>
    <td  width='100%' height='14' class='infoBoxHeading'>$heading</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' class='infoBox'>
            <tr><td>
            <table class='infoBoxContents'>
            <FORM name='m_srch' action='advanced_search_result.php' method='get'>
            <INPUT type='hidden' value='1' name='m_op'> <INPUT type='hidden' value='1' name='keywords'> \n
            $mainhtml
            </table>
            </td></tr>
            </FORM>
        </table>
    </td></tr>";  

?>
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt at using `order by`?  You might be closer than you think.

Comment: Hello Scott, I like your positivity. I have tried loads of little things. This for example


$optnamear = tep_db_query("SELECT `products_options_values_name` from `products_options_values` WHERE `products_options_values_id`='$id[products_options_values_id]' " . '"order by products_options_values_name"') ;

Answer (score 0):

## Use a join in your query.

```
SELECT products_options_values_id, products_options_values_name 
FROM products_options_values_to_products_options
  INNER JOIN products_options_values
  ON products_options_values.products_options_values_id = products_options_values_to_products_options.products_options_values_id
WHERE products_options_values_to_products_options.products_options_id='$opt'
ORDER BY products_options_values.products_options_values_name
```

And iterate on this.

Instead of:

```
SELECT products_options_values_id 
from products_options_values_to_products_options 
WHERE products_options_id='$opt'`
```

and then iterating

```
SELECT products_options_values_name 
from products_options_values 
WHERE products_options_values_id='$id[products_options_values_id]
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time. I researched "join" and it says this "combine rows from two or more tables"

I have no issues with join rows. I get the dropdown, everything works ok, its just the names in the drop down are not alphabetically ordered.

I thought just addressing this line would so the job >>$optnamear = tep_db_query("SELECT `products_options_values_name` from `products_options_values` WHERE `products_options_values_id`='$id[products_options_values_id]' ") ;<< If you answer covers this I apologise, it was over my head. Thank you again for your time anyway.

Comment: @Richard47 this is I think what you need. You have product options in one table and their names in another. These can be combined by the `JOIN` operation. So you end up with a table that both has the options and names (this is done on the database side btw). You and up with what you need by doing one query only.